# Why can I not install python-pptx using pip in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pypi, python-pptx

I am currently working on a project which involves extracting content from PowerPoint slides to text file using python-pptx package. I tried using

```
!pip install python-pptx
```

but [image: this error message] showed up.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as text.

Comment: This is not jupyter or pptx specific. There is a connection issue, so it is related to your current network/proxy settings

Comment: Also, so you know, you want to use `%pip install <package_name_here>` , or the related `%conda install`, when installing inside a notebook. That insures the installation is done in the environment backing the notebook. The modern magic commands were added to avoid the common issues encountered in the past when the exclamation point was used. Anything recommending an exclamation point for use with `pip` or `conda` is outdated. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about them.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to update pip version and check if python-ppt works with your current version of python.

thank you